# (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to update rows by routing to the `edit.blade.php` by writing in the `web.php`

```
"Route::get('/owner-information/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'owner-information.edit', 'uses' => 'OwnerInformatiionController@edit']);
```

and in the `index.blade.php`

```
{{ route('owner-information.update', $owner_info->id) }}
```

and after clicking update it shows thee following error:

```
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 
'POST'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 546)
at Router->findRoute(object(Request))
in Router.php (line 525)
```

Comment: In web.php : Route::get('/owner-information/create', ['as' => 'owner-information.create', 'uses' => 'OwnerInformatiionController@create']);
In index.blade.php : {{ route('owner-information.create') }}

Comment: You've said it was `create` method first, but now you say it's `update`. Please show the `update` route then and the form you submit to the `update` route. Or this is an `a href` link?

Comment: sorry, firstly i've mistaken (you know i'm novice here), it is update.

Comment: in web.php it is:  Route::post('/owner-information', ['as' => 'owner-information.update', 'uses' => 'OwnerInformatiionController@update']);  and in edit.blade.php it is: action="{{ route('employee-management.update', ['id' => $employee->id]) }}"

Comment: And you don't use a form, but you use a simple link, right? Do you save any data to the `update` route?

Comment: Yes, i've used form: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('employee-management.update', ['id' => $employee->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: But you send the form to a different route `employee-management.update` and not to `owner-information.update` which you've shown before.

Comment: Oh my god!! why i'm making such mistakes(my be its because my exitments, first time asking a qustion here).. extremely sorry. Actually it is: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="{{ route('owner-information.update', $owner_info->id) }}" method="post">

Comment: Please update your answer with full form code.

Comment: did you try `php artisan route:clear`? does the route address is unique? maybe the mistake is in using route name. you named the route `owner-information.edit` and used it as `owner-information-update`.

Answer (score 1):

create a `post` route for update

```
    Route::post('routeName','OwnerInformatiionController@update');
```

Comment: i have changed it as post route after that its showing me: (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST', 'DELETE'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 238)
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST', 'DELETE'))
in RouteCollection.php (line 176)

Answer (score 1):

Since your route is `post`, remove this from the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

Alternatively, you could change the route to `patch`:

```
Route::patch('owner-information/{id}', ['as' => 'owner-information.update', 'uses' => 'OwnerInformatiionController@update']);
```

Also, you need to add a parameter since you're passing it to the route. So, instead of:

```
'/owner-information'
```

It should be something like:

```
'owner-information/{id}'
```

And in the `OwnerInformatiionController@update` method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

Comment: thanks. but now its showing error like : (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\OwnerInformatiionController::update(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: You haven't shown the update method but it looks like you don't accept the ID parameter there. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i've edited the code, please check (it's not showing in right format).
Bye the way the previous error is gone. Now new error showing : 
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function store() on null

in OwnerInformatiionController.php (line 51)

Comment: Sure, of course i will accept. Let me know how to accept answer.

Comment: You're getting the new error because there is no uploaded file, so this `$request->file('picture')` is empty. You need to add a check if file was uploaded `if ($request->file('picture'))`

Comment: Solved. Thank you

Comment: another query how to accept answer? 
I didn't have enough reputation to upvote the answer.Now only 11 reputation, i'll up vote when i get 15 reputations. ok??

Comment: @KhairatHossin you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) with any rating.

Answer (score 0):

edit.blade.php
    @extends('owner-information.base')

```
@section('action-content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Update Owner Information</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="{{ route('owner-information.update', $owner_info->id) }}" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="first_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{ $owner_info->first_name }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('first_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('first_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mid_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="mid_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Middle Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="mid_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="mid_name" value="{{ $owner_info->mid_name }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('mid_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mid_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="last_name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Last Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" value="{{ $owner_info->last_name }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('last_name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('last_name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('flat_no') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="flat_no" class="col-md-4 control-label">Flat No</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="flat_no" type="text" class="form-control" name="flat_no" value="{{ $owner_info->flat_no }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('flat_no'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('flat_no') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('car_park') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="car_park" class="col-md-4 control-label">Parking No</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="car_park" type="text" class="form-control" name="car_park" value="{{ $owner_info->car_park }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('car_park'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('car_park') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('mobile_no') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="mobile_no" class="col-md-4 control-label">Mobile No</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="mobile_no" type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_no" value="{{ $owner_info->mobile_no }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('mobile_no'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('mobile_no') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">Email Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email_id" type="text" class="form-control" name="email_id" value="{{ $owner_info->email_id }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email_id'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email_id') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('n_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="n_id" class="col-md-4 control-label">National ID</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="n_id" type="text" class="form-control" name="n_id" value="{{ $owner_info->n_id }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('n_id'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('n_id') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('date_of_birth') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="date_of_birth" class="col-md-4 control-label">Date of Birth</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="date_of_birth" type="text" class="form-control" name="date_of_birth" value="{{ $owner_info->date_of_birth }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('date_of_birth'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('date_of_birth') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('present_add') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="present_add" class="col-md-4 control-label">Present Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="present_add" type="text" class="form-control" name="present_add" value="{{ $owner_info->present_add }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('present_add'))
                                <span class="help-block">present_add
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('present_add') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('parmanent_add') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="parmanent_add" class="col-md-4 control-label">Parmanent Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="parmanent_add" type="text" class="form-control" name="parmanent_add" value="{{ $owner_info->parmanent_add }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('parmanent_add'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('parmanent_add') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('emergency_contact') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="emergency_contact" class="col-md-4 control-label">Emergency Contact</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="emergency_contact" type="text" class="form-control" name="emergency_contact" value="{{ $owner_info->emergency_contact }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('emergency_contact'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('emergency_contact') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 @endsection
```

In controller: 
          public function update(Request $request, $id)
       {
        $owner_info = OwnerInfo::findOrFail($id);
       // $this->validateInput($request);
        $temp= str_replace('/', '-',$request->date_of_birth);
        $date = new DateTime($temp);
        $input = [
            'first_name'=> $request['first_name'],
            'mid_name' => $request['mid_name'],
            'last_name'=> $request['last_name'],
            'flat_no' => $request['flat_no'],
            'car_park'=> $request['car_park'],
            'mobile_no' => $request['mobile_no'],
            'email_id' => $request['email_id'],
            'n_id' => $request['n_id'],
            'date_of_birth' => $request['date'],
            'present_add' => $request['present_add'],
            'parmanent_add' => $request['parmanent_add'],
            'emergency_contact' => $request['emergency_contact']

```
          ];
      if ($request->file('picture')) {
        $path = $request->file('picture')->store('avatars');
        $input['picture'] = $path;
    }
    OwnerInfo::where('id', $id)
        ->update($input);
    return redirect()->intended('owner-information');
 }
```